# How to turn off the bell sound in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

How do you disable the bell sound in Intellij.

I am using the IdeaVim plugin for Intellij on Mac OS X and want to mute the sound.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

[This article](http://jason-stillwell.com/blog/2013/04/11/ideavim/) may help you.

Basically, IdeaVIM reads your `~/.ideavimrc` (`~/.vimrc` pre-v0.35) file and silently ignores any settings it does not understand. Of the bell-related settings, it does not understand `:set noerrorbells`, but it *does* understand `:set visualbell`. And since it has no implementation for a visual bell, it will do nothing and achieve the desired effect.

So in your `~/.ideavimrc`, you can use the following:

```
set visualbell
set noerrorbells
```

This will set the (non-functional) visual bell for IdeaVIM while disabling the bell completely for VIM itself.

Comment: Note that as of v0.35, IdeaVIM no longer uses the ~/.vimrc, it now uses ~/.ideavimrc.

Comment: This is not working for me in IntelliJ 2018.2 and IdeaVim 0.50 on Windows 10

Comment: on windows (7) it is _ideavimrc instead of .ideavimrc  in your C:\Users\<username>\  folder

Comment: _Peace (and quiet) be with you._

Comment: after doing this, I was about to lose hope, but I just had to restart _all_ of the open IntelliJ windows I had

Comment: Works perfectly in PhpStorm 2020.3.2 (Build #PS-203.7148.74)

Comment: Thanks, note that for me running IDEA 2020.3 on macOS Big Sur, I also had to restart IDEA.

Comment: This is way too many steps to disable something that is so annoying.  Can't this just be added to the plugin config UI?  Sorry, just venting.

Comment: Windows folks - don't forget to remove the `.txt` from the end of your _ideavimrc file, like I did.

Comment: This answer has aged remarkably well, 8 years! Solved it in IJ 2021.1.3, but I wonder why I only started experiencing the issue now? I've used ideavim for years!

Comment: For me, all of a sudden, I had a visual bell (screen flashes in negative colors). `set visualbell` solved my problem.

Comment: RIP annoying useless sound. 

Answer (score 12):

I wanted to disable the Bell sound throughout all of my Mac, including `AppCode`.  Did this by sliding `Alert Volume` to 0 in `System Settings > Sound` on my Mac

Comment: Blissful peace! Thanks :)

Comment: An update for those who find this post five years later like I did.  Unfortunately, system sound settings doesn't control this bell for Macos Catalina and Intellij 2020.2.  Adding `set noerrorbells` and `set visualbell` in `~/.ideavimrc` does still work.

Comment: It did for me with macOS 12.1 (Monterey) and PyCharm 2021.3

Comment: This works for me too on Monterrey 12.3. I'm not sure why the ~/.ideavimrc fix didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering why no one has mentioned disabling the audible bell from the settings. Is the OP asking something different?

[image: disabling the audible bell]

Comment: This does not disable the bell from IdeaVim. It disables the bell when navigating in the terminal (as indicated by the tab name)